# gRPC: Generate certificateChainFile and privateKeyFile to make TLS/SSL work

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, keytool

I want to make tls/ssl connection between client and server(Not mutual, one way).

This is my setup:

Server:

```
    Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(8443)
        // Enable TLS
        .useTransportSecurity(certChainFile, privateKeyFile)
        .addService(new GreetingServiceImpl())
        .build();
```

Client

```
    // With server authentication SSL/TLS
   ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 8443)
       .build();
   GreetingServiceGrpc.GreetingServiceBlockingStub stub =
            GreetingServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
```

All I need is **Terminal commands** to generate **certChainFile** and **privateKeyFile(in .pem)** to pass these file to server code as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

> All I need is Terminal commands to generate certChainFile and privateKeyFile

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout ./testkey.pem -out ./testcert.crt -days 999 -subj "/CN=localhost"
```

This command generates a an RSA key and a self-signed certificate.

But you need more than that.

1. SSL by default checks the common name (CN) equals the hostname. Therefore you need to generate certificate which has CN=localhost
2. the client must trust the server's certificate, so the certificate needs to be imported into the client's trustore (though I am not sure how to configure the trust-store for the client, I will leave it up to you).